# Virtual host in XAMPP Windows 7

Tags: php, apache, xampp, virtual-hosts

I am trying to create a virtual host in xampp windows 7.

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project/Trunk/xyz"
    ServerName xyz.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

host

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       xyz.local
```

**Edit 1:** `httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` result is given below

`VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
default server abcd (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:45)
port 80 namevhost abcd (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:45)
port 80 namevhost localhost (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:49)
port 80 namevhost xyz.local (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:53)
*:443                  www.example.com (C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:102)`

**Edit 2:** Attachment - website not found error

[image]

Calling `http://xyz.local/` shows the website not found error. But if I configure entire thing with only `xyz` (*not `.local` in the string `xyz.local`*) it is working fine after calling `http://xyz/`. I want it as `http://xyz.local/`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: That looks like it should work to me - have you restarted Apache after making the change?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only omit `NameVirtualHost` in Apache/2.4. What's your version?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - just checked the Apache 2.2 httpd-vhosts.conf on my machine and it's commented out there; don't know about earlier versions though ;)

Comment: @CD001 To be precise, you need [2.3.11 or greater](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost). Otherwise, it needs to be set. Seriously.

Comment: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8

Comment: @CD001 Yes I restarted the Apache

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I already set it and tried but same result

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario : ah, my bad, I'm running 2.4; saw `# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>` in the comments in httpd-vhosts.conf and assumed I was still running 2.2 ... must have updated my dev box at some point and just ported in the old 2.2 hosts file ;)

Comment: @KirenSiva - Why? It isn't required for 2.4. Whatever, can you edit the question and copy the output of this command? `httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`

Comment: @KirenSiva - Your actual settings do not match your *.conf files... Is it possible you're just editing the wrong files? (That's surprisingly easy to do with these third-party bundles.) In any case, even those other settings should work. When you say "website not found error" you mean the browser's error page and not some text rendered by your application, don't you?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario it is not the text rendered by your application.Hope I am editing the correct files. Because `http://xyz/` is working fine.

Comment: Just seen your second edit. You're using a proxy and you're getting a plain IP resolution problem! You probably need to configure your browser so it doesn't use a proxy for the `.local` top-level domain. It has nothing to do with Apache I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway ... that's an obsolete router/firewall/web cache ... that could be hijacking your DNS requests

Comment: Finally solved.Thank you both for the clue. I changed the browser proxy settings to bypass the proxy server for the request xyz* and it is worked as expected :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's down to a browser configuration error.